# How to get full summary from atom feed from gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

im geting summary but its not the full summarry of the bady of the mail, please someone tell how to get it

my coding:

```
    //Logging in Gmail server to get data
            objClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "password");
            //reading data and converting to string
            response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objClient.DownloadData(@"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"));


            response = response.Replace(
                 @"<feed version=""0.3"" xmlns=""http://purl.org/atom/ns#"">", @"<feed>");

            //loading into an XML so we can get information easily
            doc2.LoadXml(response);

            //nr of emails
        string nr = doc2.SelectSingleNode(@"/feed/fullcount").InnerText;

            //Reading the title and the summary for every email
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc2.SelectNodes(@"/feed/entry"))
            {
                title = node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
                summary = node.SelectSingleNode("summary").InnerText;
            }
```

Comment: That's the most you can get with atom

Comment: but i want full body of the mail how to acheive it